# codeigniter custom config file calling config data

Tags: codeigniter, config

i've a file @ /config/form_validation.php
i've another file @ /config/ion_auth.php

i tried to get the 'ion_auth data' in form_validation but failed:

```
'rules'=>'required|min_length['.$this->config->item('min_password_length', 'ion_auth').']'
```

error Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$config

If i change it to this, all works well.

```
'rules'=>'required|min_length[3]'
```

It seems that i cannot call the data from another config file at the current config file.
How to overcome this problem or is this a system limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you create form at wrong place, try to get main controller first:

```
 $CI =$ get_instence();
'rules'=>'required|min_length['.$CI->config->item('min_password_length', 'ion_auth').']'
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie, solved by doing your way: $CI =& get_instance();